# Como tipar corretamente o resultado de um findOne usando typescript, sequelize e mysql?

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, sequelize-js, model

Atualmente faço a seguinte pesquisa

```
const user: any = await UserModel.findOne({
   where: {
      email: email,
   },
});
```

Estou tipando com **any** porque preciso usar algumas colunas de tabela como **user.username** e **user.password**, mas não gostaria de tipar com **any**.

UserModel:

```
const UserModel = db.define("users", {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  username: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  email: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  password: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  access_level: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  biography: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: true,
  },
  profile_image: {
    type: DataTypes.BLOB("medium"),
    allowNull: true,
  },
});
```

Tentei criar uma **user interface** para substituir **any**, mas não funcionou

```
interface userAttributes {
  id: number;
  username: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  access_level: number;
  biography: string;
  profile_image: Blob;
}
```

O seguinte erro acontece quando eu tento tipar com o **userAttributes**
'Model<any, any> | null' is not assignable to type 'userAttributes'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'userAttributes'

Vocês podem me ajudar a tipar o resultado deste **findOne** corretamente, por favor?

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei a solução lendo a documentação do sequelize: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/typescript/

O código caso seja útil pra alguém:

```
import { CreationOptional, DataTypes, InferAttributes, InferCreationAttributes, Model } from "sequelize";
import { db } from "../database/db-connection";

class UserModel extends Model<InferAttributes<UserModel>, InferCreationAttributes<UserModel>> {
  declare id: CreationOptional<number>;
  declare username: string;
  declare email: string;
  declare password: string;
  declare access_level: number;
  declare biography: string;
  declare profile_image: Blob | string;
  declare createdAt: CreationOptional<Date>;
  declare updatedAt: CreationOptional<Date>;
}

UserModel.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    access_level: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    biography: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    profile_image: {
      type: DataTypes.BLOB("medium"),
      allowNull: true,
    },
    createdAt: DataTypes.DATE,
    updatedAt: DataTypes.DATE,
  },
  {
    sequelize: db,
    tableName: "users",
  }
);

export { UserModel };
```

```
      const user: UserModel | null = await UserModel.findOne({
        where: {
          id: id,
        },
      });
```